# Why was this question closed?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

Why was the question [Strange persisting error, even after removing the code.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12610/debugging-runaway-argument-file-ended-while-scanning-use-of-pginfo) closed without comment? Did the OP request it?

It is not a great question, but I'd have rather rewritten it to be more general („my file doesn't compile, but when I copy the code to a new file it compiles”) than close it.

Comment: No idea! Shall we vote to reopen?

Comment: @Hendrik: I was hoping to get an explanation, as Martin surely had a reason for closing the question. But in the absence of that we can surly vote to reopen.

Comment: Maybe you could notify Martin directly? I've also voted to reopen (since your question is already 3 hours old), but I think it would be hard to get three more reopen votes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was under the impression that the error is gone for the OP (because of his comment) and that it is simply the common "some stuff left in the .aux file" error (because of his and our comments). Because of the specific title of the question I also saw no general value for future occasions of the general .aux file error.

Actually I just wanted to flag it as 'too localized' to notify the other mods about it, but was then surprised that this already closed it. I know that one close vote of a mod is enough to close a question, but wasn't aware the flagging does the same. After I saw that it was closed I just let it like it was. I didn't added a comment because I thought the two comments already explained it very well. (Also I had a quite busy day at work ...)

I have no problem with reopening the question. Sorry for that.

Anyway, I can't reproduce this error as described. The file compiles fine in the first and all future runs. I tried multiple filenames.

Comment: Ah, this flagging thing is a good explanation. Joseph should be able to help out on that one: I think he's done some flagging for his own future reference before.

Comment: I agree that the "whoops, I left out a (semicolon|space|keyword)" questions, where there is some simple oversight that 'fixes' the problem, are of little value to anyone. If that's what this is...

Comment: I certainly flagged stuff for further notice when a pro tem so it can be done.  Maybe you hit the "close" button rather than the "flag" one.

Comment: @Jeff: I think the problem is more subtle than a forgotten semicolon. New users don't necessarily know that the .aux file can go bad.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Maybe there should be some testing area for mod tools (you can abuse this question, if you like).